# Passing Parameters to facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

After lots of try I'm still stuck, I wanted to confirm one thing when passing parameters to a facebook application.

Does every parameters gets passed to the application, for e.g. if i've an application running

https://apps.facebook.com/example/index.php, and I do this https://apps.facebook.com/example/index.php?app_data={"para1":"para1"}, will this  be passed??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the parameter, I'm simply doing $_GET and retrieving the parameter from a typical URL like apps.facebook.com//index.php?var=

so, on index.php, I'm simply doing

$_GET['var'] and thus getting the var

Answer (score 2):

Yes, In canvas apps, every parameter is passed.

For fan page apps, you will get data in app_data parameter as json string. 
https://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=any_string_here

FYI: [Signed Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

```
    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$app_data = '';
if(isset($signed_request["app_data"])){
    $app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];
    }
```